# Android: all elements displayed on top of the screen

Tags: android, mobile

I am new in mobile development and I am trying to run my activity and view the result of my layout with my phone/emulator.
On the design mode it looks good but when I run it on the emulator/phone all the elements are ordered one on top of another.

I have these files:

**activity_item_page.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                                             xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
                                             xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
                                             android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                             android:layout_height="match_parent"
                                             android:weightSum="1"
                                             android:baselineAligned="false"
                                             android:orientation="vertical"
                                             tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="81dp"
                                             tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="0dp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/product_name"
        android:layout_width="343dp"
        android:layout_height="29dp"
        android:text="@string/nike_show"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        tools:ignore="MissingConstraints"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="9dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"/>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/item_data_info"
        android:layout_width="344dp"
        android:layout_height="199dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="8dp"
        tools:ignore="MissingConstraints,NotSibling"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/item_tab"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"/>


        <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="165dp"
            android:layout_height="134dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:scrollbars="none"
            tools:ignore="MissingConstraints,RtlHardcoded"
            android:id="@+id/constraintLayout2"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="98dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/product_name"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/item_tab">

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/id_gallery"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="50dp"
                tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="677dp"
                android:layout_below="@id/product_name"
                tools:ignore="NotSibling,UnknownId">
            </LinearLayout>

        </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="344dp"
        android:layout_height="54dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.1"
        tools:ignore="MissingConstraints,NotSibling"
        android:id="@+id/item_tab"
        android:layout_below="@+id/id_gallery"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="238dp"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent">

        <android.support.design.widget.TabItem
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/description"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="31dp"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="856dp"/>

        <android.support.design.widget.TabItem
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/history"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="165dp"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="856dp"/>

        <android.support.design.widget.TabItem
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/alerts"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="288dp"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="856dp"/>
    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

**ItemPageActivity.java**

```
package com.goldbergtom.cricket;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.HorizontalScrollView;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class ItemPageActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private LinearLayout mGallery;
    private int[] mImgIds;
    private LayoutInflater mInflater;
    private HorizontalScrollView horizontalScrollView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_item_page);
        mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(this);
        initData();
        initView();
    }

    private void initData()
    {
        mImgIds = new int[] { R.drawable.ic_1, R.drawable.ic_2, R.drawable.ic_3,R.drawable.ic_4
        };
    }

    private void initView()
    {
        mGallery = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.id_gallery);

        for (int i = 0; i < mImgIds.length; i++)
        {

            View view = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_gallery_item,
                    mGallery, false);
            ImageView img = (ImageView) view
                    .findViewById(R.id.id_index_gallery_item_image);
            img.setImageResource(mImgIds[i]);
            TextView txt = (TextView) view
                    .findViewById(R.id.id_index_gallery_item_text);
            txt.setText("info "+i);
            mGallery.addView(view);
        }
    }
}
```

I am also attaching images of the design and emulator.
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I was needed to set the objects exactly to constraints rules.